# OpenGL post-processing after drawing is complete

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I am working with an Android library that renders 2D images using OpenGL in a `GLSurfaceView`.

My goal is to add some post-processing effects to the final image.

The source for the library is not available. However, I am able to subclass the `Renderer` and add anything I need into `onSurfaceChanged`, `onSurfaceCreated`, and `onDrawFrame`.

One approach I considered is to bind a new FBO before calling `super.onDrawFrame`. Then, render that FBO to the screen buffer using my own shader program. But, I don't think this will work because the library would already be drawing to the screen buffer, and likely calling glFinish() -- I don't know of a way to avoid this.

Is there anything I can do to add my own post-processing?

Answer (score 1):

You can 1.use `glReadPixel` to transfer pixel from default FBO. 2.then create your own FBO and texture. 3.upload the pixel as texture. 4. bind your FBO and apply your post-processing shader. 5. bind default FBO then render to screen.